# How do I solve "error: no matching package named `` found"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Goal: Fix the following error, and have my `chain.rs` file to be able to access the functions in the `crypto.rs` file.

`crypto` is a file in my project I created, not a external crate that can be found on https://crates.io/.

After entering: **cargo run**...

```
error: no matching package named `crypto` found
location searched: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\---\fuzz\crypto
required by package `project v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\---\fuzz\chain)`
```

Background: I have a project and the directory looks like this.
[Directory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaMPZ.png)

To reproduce this, download the repository here: https://github.com/LixurProtocol/Lixur. Then run `chain.rs` with cargo.

I want to import the contents from `crypto.rs` to `chain.rs` using this .toml file.

```
[package]
name = "project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
crypto = { path = "../crypto" }
chrono = "0.4.19"
sha2 = "0.10.2"
thousands = "0.2.0"
random_choice = "0.3.2"
serde = { version = "1.0.140", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.82"

[[bin]]
name = "chain"
path = "src/chain.rs"
```

I've seen from this link (https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6686) that I need a config.toml file but I can't find one on my device.

Things I've tried: Updating cargo, tracking down the location of my config.toml file (Couldn't find it anywhere)

So, how do I fix this? Do I make a config.toml file? How do I create one?

Comment: My problem was that my library's name under [package] was not correct when I was trying to reference it (via my private git repo) from another project.

Answer (score 1):

To use another crate as a dependency, it must be a *library*, and your `crypto.rs` file does *look* like a library. However, your `crypto/Cargo.toml` has it marked as a binary (notice the `[[bin]]` section).

To make it a library use `[lib]` instead.

Comment: Applying this answer has resulted in this:

Comment: `invalid type: map, expected a string for key "lib"`

Comment: Looks like you tried `[[lib]]` whereas it should be simply `[lib]`

Comment: Unfortunately, your recommendation didn't work...

Comment: `error: no matching package named "crypto" found
location searched: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\---\---\crypto
required by package "project v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\---\--- Protocol\chain)"`

Comment: If that path is correct, you might need to change `[package] name = "project"` to `[package] name = "crypto"`